# Customize windows store app on taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, windows-store-app

How can I create a custom icon for a windows store app and pin it to the taskbar? Creating a shortcut for the program (which works great for real programs) does not work for a store app. The shortcut looks and acts like it should in a folder but when I pin it to the taskbar it just reverts back to the store icon.

The screenshot shows what I'm trying to do.

[image: IMG:]